# Como buscar informações de outra planilha no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho um sistema que gera planilhas .xls diariamente, exemplo "matriz_070120150900.xls". Onde os números representam o dia e hora 07/01/2015 as 09:00. Criei uma planilha para gerenciamento destes dados chamada gerencia.xls. Como faço para que gerencia.xls identifique o arquivo matriz_xxxxxxxxxxxx.xls para que eu possa realizar operações dos dados de matriz_xxxxxxxxxxxx.xls na planilha gerencia.xls?

Obs.: matriz_070120150900.xls varia de acordo com o dia. Hoje é matriz_070120150900.xls, amanha será outra planilha matriz_080120151000.xls

Eu consigo buscar de uma planilha com o nome fixo:

```
Exemplo:

matriz_070120150900.xls
A1 - Salário
B1 - R$100.000

gerencia.xls
A1 - Diretor
B1 - =[matriz_070120150900.xls]Salário!$B$1
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, Como buscar informações de outra planilha você já sabe como fazer. Porém gostaria de fazer isso dinâmicamente e não manual?

Comment: Sim, exato. Porem, preciso somar os valores da planilha (dinamicamente) matriz_070120150900.xls com a planilha do dia seguinte matriz_080120151000.xls, que será gerada as 08/01 as 10:00

Comment: O sistema gera planilhas com as mesmas colunas. Preciso que a planilha gerancia.xls identifique as planilhas com o nome que inicia com "matriz_" e some os valores da coluna "B1", por exemplo.

Comment: Não é a solução mas uma grande ajuda para tua pergunta, olha este link http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1042

Comment: a planilha `gerencia.xls` pega as informações das planilhas anteriores ou somente da do dia atual? Todas planilhas, inclusive a `gerencia.xls`, ficam na mesma pasta?

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a formula =INDIRETO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Formula utilizada neste exemplo: CÉLULA B3 da tabela gerencia.xls
=INDIRETO(    CONCATENAR(   "[";   B1;   ".xlsx]Plan1!B1");   VERDADEIRO)

Answer (score 0):

São alguns passos para concretizar o que está querendo aqui...

1. Identificar as planilhas

Pelo que vi no seu exemplo,  o nome varia não só em função da data, mas também da hora, pois em um dos arquivos citados colocou '0900' = '9:00h' e outro com '1000' = '10:00'.

1.1 Caso tenha um padrão que altere somente a data fica mais fácil, pois geraria no arquivo 'gerencia.xls' uma rotina para criar o nome dos arquivos de maneira a pegar uma data específica, do dia ou do dia anterior, se for o caso.

```
' Para pegar o arquivo de hoje
="matriz_"&TEXTO(AGORA();"ddmmaaaa")&"1000"
```

Adapte o exemplo acima para buscar a data desejada na hora desejada, podendo se uma hora fixa.

1.2 Caso não tenha esse nome do arquivo fixo, poderá criar uma pasta específica que terá apenas o arquivo que deseja ler e fazer uma rotina (função) para ler todos os arquivos desta pasta conforme esse modelo que achei:

[Lista todos os arquivos de uma pasta](http://guiadoexcel.com.br/listar-todos-os-arquivos-de-um-diretorio)

Esse código está bem completo e poderá adaptar para buscar de uma pasta fixa e do tipo '.xls' fixo conforme sua necessidade.

Apos saber o arquivo que tem de ser referenciado, poderá buscar os dados!

2. Busca dos dados

2.1 A busca dos dados pode ser de maneira direta conforme demonstrou no seu exemplo, se funcionar conforme deseja, ok!

2.2 Caso queira copiar esses dados, pode ter uma 'aba' temporária para copiar os dados, trabalhar e gravar na tabela desejada. Dependendo da complexidade da busca, se tem filtros a serem feitos etc, utilizo uma conexão direta via ODBC (Excel Files) para filtrar usando SQL os dados que quero e os filtros necessários. Em alguns projeto que tenho fiz utilizei essa função abaixo que poder ser adaptada conforme sua demanda:

```
Sub SQLPesq(ByRef WHAREHOUSE As String, ByRef PATHFILE As String, ByRef PATH As String)

' Macro para pesquisar no arquivo selecionado, dados do armazém selecionado

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & PATHFILE & ";DefaultDir" _
    ), Array( _
    "=" & PATH & ";DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;" _
    )), Destination:=Range(WHAREHOUSE)).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT `RESUMO$`.Clientes, `RESUMO$`.`Descrição do Armazém`, `RESUMO$`.IE, `RESUMO$`.`Tipo de Grão`, `RESUMO$`.`Total Geral`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "FROM `RESUMO$` `RESUMO$`" _
    )
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "tbl" & WHAREHOUSE
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Após essa busca teria a forma como trabalhar os dados, manipular, formatar e gravar essas informações na tabela, mas acho que ficaria fora do escopo do que perguntou.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Apesar de não haver nada de errado com o uso de VBA, eu daria preferência para a resposta que usa fórmulas, sem VBA. A razão é que é mais acessível.